# Black screen on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: video, display, ubuntu-12.04

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm experiencing some problems.
The first thing I noticed is that when I click the Workspace switcher all I get is a black screen (I can guess where the different workspaces are located and clicked on them, not a practical solution though).
In addition when I lock the screen or suspend the laptop (a Vaio VPCEB4M1E) I get a shifted screen (I see the right most vertical stripe on the left size of the monitor and nothing about all the rest, to put it clearly I can see the gear that allows me to turn the pc off, etc, but not much more..)
when I go to the additional driver menu I see the "ATI/AMD  proprietary FGLRX graphics driver" are installed and the post-release update version is available.
I don't know if the problem is driver related, so before doing anything I'd like to get some suggestions from you guys.
Thanks you!

Comment: Try asking at the askubuntu site of stackexchange

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Try asking your question at http://askubuntu.com/ - there you should get help for your problem.